# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo XLS línea a línea con VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Buenas a todos y todas.

Estoy intentando crear un programa que abra un archivo (esto ya lo hace) y que lea cada línea en un bucle para guardarla en un array.

La cuestión es que sé hacerlo para un csv pero no sé cómo podría hacerlo en un fichero XLS.

El fichero XLS tiene n líneas por lo que el bucle sería hasta la última línea o final del archivo.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bien, no sabemos cómo son tus datos, así que he creado un ejemplo sencillo, a ver si te puede servir para tus necesidades.

He diseñado una sencilla tabla en Excel con datos. Mis datos empiezan en la Celda A1 y terminan en la celda C32. Cada celda, lo único que contiene es `Nº Fila || Nº Columna`.

Bien, yo quiero llevarme todos esos datos a un array (matriz). Es decir, me quiero llevar las 32 líneas.

```
1||1    1||2    1||3
2||1    2||2    2||3
3||1    3||2    3||3
4||1    4||2    4||3
5||1    5||2    5||3
6||1    6||2    6||3
7||1    7||2    7||3
8||1    8||2    8||3
9||1    9||2    9||3
10||1   10||2   10||3
11||1   11||2   11||3
12||1   12||2   12||3
13||1   13||2   13||3
14||1   14||2   14||3
15||1   15||2   15||3
16||1   16||2   16||3
17||1   17||2   17||3
18||1   18||2   18||3
19||1   19||2   19||3
20||1   20||2   20||3
21||1   21||2   21||3
22||1   22||2   22||3
23||1   23||2   23||3
24||1   24||2   24||3
25||1   25||2   25||3
26||1   26||2   26||3
27||1   27||2   27||3
28||1   28||2   28||3
29||1   29||2   29||3
30||1   30||2   30||3
31||1   31||2   31||3
32||1   32||2   32||3
```

Y un pantallazo de los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para llevarme todos esos datos a un Array, entonces utilizaría el siguiente código.

```
Sub LLENAR_ARRAY()
Dim MiArray As Variant 'Será nuestro Array
Dim UltimaFila As Long 'Guardaremos nuestra última fila con datos, contando desde abajo, para asegurar que guardamos todas las líneas
Dim UltimaColumna As Long 'Guardaremos nuestra ultima columna con datos, para asegurar que guardamos todas las columnas

UltimaFila = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
UltimaColumna = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

MiArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UltimaFila, UltimaColumna)).Value

'ahora la variable Array es una matriz acorde a las dimensiones de tu rango de datos.
'será bidimensional, es decir, tendrá 2 index.
'Para acceder a un elemento concreto del array, simplemente selecciona en qué fila  columna está.
'2 ejemplos.

Debug.Print MiArray(1, 1) 'devolverá el elemento que esté en fila 1 y columna 1 de mi rango de datos
Debug.Print MiArray(5, 3) 'devolverá el elemento que esté en la fila 5, columna 3 de mi rango de datos

Debug.Print LBound(MiArray) 'esta función nos devuelve el index mínimo de datos (siempre será 1 si creas el array de esta manera)
Debug.Print UBound(MiArray)  'esta función nos devuelve el index máximo de datos (el nº de la última fila de datos)

'Jugando con Ubound, puedes crear bucles, para ir modificando los datos del array como quieras.
'Por ejemplo, vamos a imprimir los 10 primeros de la segunda columna
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To UBound(MiArray) Step 1
    Debug.Print MiArray(i, 2)
    If i = 10 Then Exit For
Next i

Erase MiArray 'borra todo el contenido de la matriz. Liberamos memoria y podemos volver a utilizarla con otro rango de datos

End Sub
```

Espero que esta respuesta pueda servirte, o al menos orientarte y que puedas aplicarlo a tus necesidades. También he subido el archivo a mi Google Drive por si quieres descargarlo y chequearlo tú mismo. https://drive.google.com/file/d/124YZqsIEkG5HGmfzM7lylFWUWVW465uS/view?usp=sharing

> **IMPORTANTE:** Donde digo que con Lbound obtienes el índex mínimo del Array, esto es cierto. Luego digo que el mínimo será siempre 1. Esto
>   no es cierto. El índex mínimo será 1 siempre y cuando crees un array
>   siguiendo el método `Array = RangoDatos.Value` Otros métodos de
>   creación de Arrays hacen que el índex mínimo sea 0. Pero en este caso
>   que he puesto yo, sí, mínimo siempre será 1, porque la matriz se
>   estructura con `Array(nº fila,nºcolumna)`. Es como el juego de hundir
>   barcos.

Comment: Gracias. Siguiendo tu ejemplo me queda claro.