# ¿Cómo asignar un valor dentro de una variable Range?

Tags: excel, funciones, vba, macros

En VBA en Excel, se ha implementando una función que regresa un valor `Double`, se envía como parámetro una matriz `Range`. Dentro de la función, se desea trabajar con una copia de la matriz, para evitar cambiar los valores de la matriz original en la hoja de cálculo.

Suponiendo que se tiene lo siguiente

```
Dim COPIA As Range
Set COPIA = MATRIZ
...'Algunas operaciones
COPIA(1,1) = 1.0
```

Pero cuando se invoca la función, sale `#VALUE` y no se logra determinar el error. Haciendo pruebas, la última sentencia no deja terminar la función. ¿Cómo se asigna un solo valor dentro de una variable `Range`, sin que arroje error la función?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una variable de tipo `Range` se utiliza para hacer mención a un rango de datos, el cual puede ser una celda o conjunto de celdas.

Imaginemos unos datos como los que tengo en la siguiente imagen. Mis datos empiezan en la celda C3, y terminan en la celda E5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para asignar ese rango de datos a una variable en VBA sería:

```
Dim MiRango As Range
Set MiRango = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:E5")
```

Nuestro rango es de 3x3. Para modificar algún elemento del rango, entonces hay que usar la propiedad `Cells`. Por ejemplo. si escribimos en VBA:

```
MiRango.Cells(1, 1).Value = 25
```

Sustituiremos el valor 1 por el valor 25. La sintaxis es `Range.Cells(x,y)` donde y sería el número de columna del elemento objetivo y x sería el número de fila del elemento objetivo.

> **IMPORTANTE: Cuando usas una variable tipo Range, se vincula a los datos de origen,** así que si cambias algún valor dentro del rango,
>   entonces se cambia también en la celda afectada.

Otra cosa diferente son los arrays o matrices.

> Es una copia de un rango de datos pero no está vinculado al origen de
>   datos. Es decir, los cambios que hagas en el array se almacenan en la
>   memoria, y no se reflejan en la hoja de cálculo

Hay varios métodos, pero te pongo un enlace de otra respuesta de este foro donde se explica bien como crear un Array, meterle datos, sacarlo, a ver si te puede servir:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/186012/74355