# Depurar Archivo varias condiciones

Tags: excel, vba

Muy buenos días a todos,

Les cuento el problema, estoy creando una Macro con el cual pretendo depurar un archivo Excel que descargamos de otra fuente y contiene varios miles de registros, pero me he topado con lo siguiente en lo que no tengo idea de como poder atacarlo.

***EDITO, por detallar mas la pregunta.
Detallo un poco mas lo que necesito:
Una disculpa por no contestar antes, basicamente lo que necesito es de la imagen mostrada anteriormente.
Tomar de la columna "F" el ID mientras el ID sea el mismo y si en la columna "E", se encuentra un texto "SProd - Short" y en ese row tiene cualquier valor de estos 25, 50, 75, 100 en la columna "L" e inmediatamente despues de esa linea en la columna "E" hay un texto "SProd" entonces actualiza la columna "L" en ese renglon con el valor arriba de el (25,50,75,100)  el resto de registros que no cumplan con la condicion eliminarlos y/o marcarlos en un color.***

Como comento ya he depurado bastante el archivo con este Macro que he ido diseñando, pero la parte que les comento no tengo idea de como poder atacarlo.

Les dejo una imagen de como deberia de quedar lo que esta en color rojo seria basicamente borrarlo y/o extraer en otra hoja lo marcado en verde.

El macro es este:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim i As Long
Dim UltimaFila As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Master").UsedRange.ClearContents
Sheets("Data").UsedRange.ClearContents

'On Error GoTo Errors
Windows("Log.xlsx").Activate '

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Y").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

Windows("Get_Data.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Debugin"



    Range("L2").Select
    UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

   Range("L2").Select
   For i = 2 To UltimaFila


    Select Case Cells(i, 12).Value
        Case Is = 0
            Cells(i, 13).Value = "REVIEW"
        Case Is = 24
            Cells(i, 13).Value = "REVIEW"
        Case Is = 25
            Cells(i, 13).Value = "REVIEW"
        Case Is = 50
            Cells(i, 13).Value = "REVIEW"
        Case Is = 75
            Cells(i, 13).Value = "REVIEW"
        Case Is = 100
            Cells(i, 13).Value = "REVIEW"
    End Select
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Z").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="REVIEW" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd


    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Z").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "SProd", "SProd - End", "SProd - Short"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues

   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

   Sheets("ata").Select
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

   Sheets("Master").Select
   If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
   Sheets("Master").UsedRange.ClearContents

   Sheets("Data").Select
   Range("E1").Select

   MsgBox "Finished!!!!", vbExclamation, "Finished!!!!!"

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he realizado un poco chapucera, con la grabadora de Macros.
Alguna idea con menos lineas de codigo?

```
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Produced Pcs"
    Range("E1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("F633").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[7]"
    Range("F633").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F633"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("F2:F633").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$633").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="0"
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$633").AutoFilter Field:=6
    Range("F2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$633").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="0"
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$162").AutoFilter Field:=6
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 6750054
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("M2").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$162").AutoFilter Field:=6
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("E1").Select
```

Comment: Te lo puedes llevar todo a una matriz, hacer un bucle en la columna que puede contener lo de lo de `Sprod -Short`, si se cumple, chequear lo del 0 en su columna, y en caso positivo, copiar ese subíndice de la matriz y el siguiente. Para saber cómo llevar datos de Excel a una matriz, puedes leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/186012/74355)

Comment: Añado el código que solicita en su mismo post...

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego por favor, es importante no modificar el código de quien pregunta más allá del formato si esto ayuda a la legibilidad (y si no afecta el hallar la causa de los problemas reportados). Si deseas responder, por favor ve a la caja de respuesta. Si deseas que el OP añada info a su pregunta, indícaselo en un comentario

Comment: @Alfabravo. Queda claro asi? "Introduzca después de `Cells(i, 13).Value = "REVIEW"
    End Select` este código ```    If Cells(i,5).Value2 = "SProd - Short" Then
        If( Cells(i+1,5).Value2 = "SProd") and (Cells(i,13).Value2 <> 0) Then
            *Añada el código de lo que quiera hacer, que no queda claro*
        End If
    End If``` Dado que el usuario no indica qué es lo que pretende hacer, sencillamente he añadido el código de la condición que busca para que prosiga con su planteamiento. No puedo dar una respuesta porque la pregunta es incompleta.

Comment: @Alfabravo
Una disculpa por no contestar antes, basicamente lo que necesito es de la imagen mostrada anteriormente.
Tomar de la columna "F" el ID mientras el ID sea el mismo y si en la columna "E", se encuentra un texto "SProd - Short" y en ese row tiene cualquier valor de estos 25, 50, 75, 100 en la columna "L" e inmediatamente despues de esa linea en la columna "E" hay un texto "SProd" entonces actualiza la columna "L" en ese renglon con el valor arriba de el (25,50,75,100)  el resto de registros que no cumplan con la condicion eliminarlos y/o marcarlos en un color.
DS