# ¿Como buscar registros en tabla de Access desde Excel usando VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, macros

Estoy haciendo una macro que busca registros en una tabla de access desde excel, el unico problema que tengo es que me busca solo el dato de la primera celda del rango de valores que debe recorrer haciendo el mismo procedimiento de busqueda de registros, como puedo solucionar esto? les agradecería me brindaran su ayuda a mejorar esta macro y cumplir con el proposito que ya les describí, estoy utilizando la siguiente macro:

```
Sub consultarAccess()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim datos As Object
    Dim ConsultaSql  As String
    Dim conexion As String
    Dim cont As Long
    Dim i, j
    Dim MiRango As String
    
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\VINCULACION\INSUMOS\SIGMOVILIDAD_2012.mdb"
    cn.Open conexion
    
    Uf = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 10 To Uf
     MiRango = Range("A" & i)
     ConsultaSql = "Select * from CAT_DOMINIO_REFERENCIA where INTERNO_DOMINIO = " & MiRango
    Next i

    With Worksheets("VH")
    Set datos = cn.Execute(ConsultaSql)
    datos.MoveFirst
    j = 10
     For cont = 10 To Uf
      Do While Not datos.EOF Or datos.BOF
        .Range("B" & cont) = datos.Fields("DESCRIPCION_DOMINIO")
        .Range("C" & cont) = datos.Fields("PALABRA_CLAVE")
        cont = cont + 1
        datos.MoveNext
      Loop
     Next cont
    End With
    
    datos.Close
    Set datos = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Los datos quen tengo los tengo apartir de la celda A10 de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muesta en la imagen en la columna A desde la fila 10 en adelante estan los datos de consulta desde excel hacia una base de datos de access (un rango de datos del 1 al 7989), y adyacentes a estos valores de busqueda (celdas B10 y C10) se encuentra el resultado de la macro que comparto anteriormente, es decir el procedimiento solo me busca el primer valor que en este caso es la celda con valor de 1.

Comment: Llevate todos los valores del rango a una matriz, y haz un bucle que repita los pasos, cambiando la matriz. O directamente haz un bucle.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes He intentado llevarme todos los valores del rango a una matriz, y hacer un bucle que repita los pasos, cambiando la matriz o hacer directamente un bucle con el código que tengo pero aún no me ha resultado. agradeceria tua yauda en el tema.

Comment: tienes ya un bucle FOR, donde vas asignando el valor de `MiRango` Mete **antes del bucle** la parte en la que defines la conexión. Mete **dentro** del bucle la parte en la que defines el sql, y haces el volcado de datos, y limpias el objeto `datos`. Y finalmente, **después** del bucle, mete el cerrar la conexión a la base de datos

Comment: Sobre matrices bidimensiones en VBA, puede servirte esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/186012/74355

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de cómo tienes los datos, y cómo deberían quedar, porque por lo que veo, por cada celda de A vuelcas **más de una fila**

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes amplie un poco la pregunta, con un ejemplo de lo que tengo actualmente, de igual forma agradezco el aporte dado en tus comentarios, estoy tratando de solucionarlo, soy nuevo en esto y he aprendido de manera autodidactica todo sobre vba y macros en excel ya que son muy utiles.

Comment: puede ser que simplemente este mal tu query? no podes hacer where INTERNO_DOMINIO = rango.. sql no funciona asi, si no que si vos queres revisar contra un rango tenes que usar in, pero los valores deben estar separados por coma, y no es como excel devuelve un rango... o sea, simplemente no estas buscando todos los valores que vos queres...

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu comentario voy a tenerlo en cuenta, si algo me sale bien con tu sugerencia y puedo lograrlo en las lineas de codigo , lo estare registrando en la respuesta para compartir la macro

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes he hecho lo que me dices como muestro en la edicion del codigo de la pregunta pero me sigue dando el resultado solo en la primera celda de busqueda aunque al ejecutarla noto que recorre todos los valores de rango que debe buscar pero los copia siempre en la misma celda que menciono.

Comment: @gbianchi trate de hacerlo como me recomendaste pero no consegui ejecutarla por completo siempre me daba algun error y pues hice una edicion de la macro que muestro en la pregunta aunque aun no logro dar el resultado esperado al ejecutarla.

Comment: fijate que ahora, solo ejecutas una query... la variable ConsultaSql  solo tiene el valor del ultimo registro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro de si va a funcionar, pero te dejas la query fuera del bucle que exportas, con lo cual, exportas solo una vez.

Prueba esto. No creo que sea perfecto, pero a lo mejor te vuelca algo más y lo vemos. A ver si esto puedes adaptarlo

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim datos As Object
Dim ConsultaSql  As String
Dim conexion As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim MiRango As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\VINCULACION\INSUMOS\SIGMOVILIDAD_2012.mdb"
cn.Open conexion

Uf = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 10 To Uf
    MiRango = Range("A" & i).Value
    ConsultaSql = "Select * from CAT_DOMINIO_REFERENCIA where INTERNO_DOMINIO = " & MiRango
    
    Set datos = cn.Execute(ConsultaSql)
    datos.MoveFirst
    
    With Worksheets("VH")
        j = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'primera fila libre en columna B de hoja VH
        
        Do While Not datos.EOF Or datos.BOF
            .Range("B" & j) = datos.Fields("DESCRIPCION_DOMINIO")
            .Range("C" & j) = datos.Fields("PALABRA_CLAVE")
            datos.MoveNext
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    End With
    
    datos.Close
    Set datos = Nothing
Next i


cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```