# ¿Como recorrer una constante matricial con nombre asignado en Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, matriz

Esto es un ejemplo bastante simplificado de lo que estoy haciendo respecto al número de celdas implicadas.
En Excel tengo un nombre "Celdas1" que contiene:

=(B1;B3;B4)

Quiero recorrer esta constante matricial con VBA.
He probado lo siguiente:çç

```
Sub Vaciar_nombres()
    Dim R1() As Range

    REM En la siguiente linea me salta error.
    R1 = hoja_de_pruebas.Names("Celdas1").RefersTo

    Debug.Print (VarType(R1))
End Sub
```

No he trabajado con constantes matriciales y menos usarlos con VBA.
Como puedo coger una constante matricial para posteriormente recorrer los rangos que están en esa matriz usando VBA? (Ya conozco los loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver, tu código no está bien y además estás mezclando cosas diferentes, nombres con matrices y con rangos, y hay que hacer cambios.

Un nombre, por simplificarlo, hace referencia a una serie de celdas (en tu caso, la B1,B3 y B4). Pero es un objeto de tipo `Name`

Una celda o conjunto de celdas es un objeto de tipo `Range`. Tiene otros métodos y propiedades totalmente diferentes a `Name`

Y por último, están las matrices, que en VBA pueden ser definidas de varias maneras. Normalmente lo que se suele hacer es llevarse todo un rango de celdas a una matriz, porque así el tiempo de ejecución es menor. Este proceso, muy habitual, crea siempre matrices **bidimensionales**, es decir, que para llamar a un valor de la matriz, tienes que especificar siempre un número de fila y un número de columna. No tiene propiedades y métodos como el objeto `Range` o el objeto `Name`.

Simplificando mucho, una diferencia fundamental entre el objeto `Range` y una matriz, que a simple vista puede parecer que hacen lo mismo (un conjunto de celdas con valores), hay una diferencia fundamental: las matrices almacenan **el valor** dentro de la celda, no la referencia a la propia celda, con lo que si el valor de la celda cambia, en la matriz sigue guardado el valor antiguo (tienes que forzar la actualización del valor en la matriz). Sin embargo, el objeto `Range`, cada vez que lo invocas, te va a devolver el valor que haya en ese momento exacto en la celda, incluso si ha cambiado a lo largo de tu código. Pero en tiempo de ejecución tarda más tiempo.

**OPINIÓN 100% PERSONAL:** Si trabajas con muchos valores (y cuando digo muchos valores, hablo de trabajar con cientos de celdas a la vez), deberías plantearte usar matrices. Si trabajas con poquitas celdas, puede que te resulte más sencillo el objeto `Range`

Sobre matrices, quizás te pudiera interesar echar un ojo a esta respuesta, que lo explica muy simplificado.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/186012/74355

En relación a tu código, no me queda claro lo que estás intentando hacer. Entiendo que quieres llevarte los valores de las celdas B1,B3 y B4 a una matriz. Y esa referencia la tienes almacenada en un objeto `Name`.

Te adelanto que **no puedes llevarte en un solo paso a una matriz** un conjunto de celdas no adyacentes. Es decir, La celda B3 y B4 son adyacentes, pero B1 no porque saltaste la B2. Y por ello, no puedes llevarte todo de golpe a una matriz bidimensional. Tienes que llevarte los valores de 1 en 1

Luego, tienes que tener claro si tu nombre está definido como ámbito de Libro o ámbito de Hoja. En mi ejemplo, está definido como ámbito de Libro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate que además la he definido con referencias absolutas (el símbolo del $).

Sobre referencias absolutas, mírate bien este enlace, porque es importante entenderlo:

> [Alternar entre referencias relativas, absolutas y
> mixtas](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/alternar-entre-referencias-relativas-absolutas-y-mixtas-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

La propiedad `RefersTo` devuelve o establece la fórmula a la que debe hacer referencia el nombre, en la notación de estilo A1 y el lenguaje de la macro, comenzando con un signo igual. String de lectura y escritura

> [Propiedad Name. RefersTo
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.name.refersto)

Además, las celdas a las que hago referencia tienen estos valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código coge **el rango** del nombre `Celdas1` (que está definido como ámbito Libro). Cuenta el total de celdas, redimensiona la matriz **unidimensional** y se lleva los valores a la matriz. Y luego ya me paseo por la matriz y devuelvo todos y cada uno de los valores.

Por si no los conoces, mírate bien que funciones nativas de VBA puedes usar con matrices:

> [Función
> Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)
>
> [Función
> Ubound](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)
>
> [Función
> LBound](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/lbound-function)
>
> [Instrucción
> Erase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/erase-statement)
>
> [Instrucción
> Redim](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement)

Y este es mi código:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim MiMatriz() As Variant
Dim i As Long

ReDim MiMatriz(1 To Range("Celdas1").Count) 'redimensiono matriz

i = 1
For Each rng In Range("Celdas1")
    MiMatriz(i) = rng.Value
    i = i + 1
Next rng

'ahora devuelvo todos los valores
For i = 1 To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    Debug.Print MiMatriz(i)
Next i

Erase MiMatriz
```

Y cuando lo ejecuto, la ventana inmediato me devuelve estos valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate bien que el número 20 no lo devuelve, porque ese valor estaba en la celda B2, que **no está incluida** en el nombre Celdas1

Espero que esto te pueda servir y adaptarlo un poco, porque como he dicho, no tengo claro lo que quieres hacer, pero prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Mil gracias de veras.
Conocía de bucles pero realmente la explicación es muy buena y detallada y me ha servido!
En mi caso además el simple hecho de usar ese rango de celdas separadas como Range, no lo había probado en lugar de usar un nombre como estaba haciendo. No sabía que se usaba Range directamente.
Mil gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo. Espero que le sirva a más gente.

Comment: Gran respuesta, muy buena y completa Elier.

Answer (score 2):

Mira el ejemplo. Con este código recorres el rango "celdas", previamente asignado. También si lo necesitas, podrías asignar los valores del rango a una matriz (si lo necesitas dímelo y te digo como)

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("celdas")
    MsgBox "busca el valor stringabuscar en " & c.Value & " en el rango celdas"
    If c.Value = "stringabuscar" Then
      MsgBox "stringabuscar encontrado en " & c.Address
    End If
Next c
```